# Is it possible for more than one flight to have the same departure and arrival time slots?

Tags: air-traffic-control, air-traffic-management

I'm working with real ATFM data such as the planned departure and arrival times of several flights within a given period of time, and I came across a surprising feature.

I found out that some flights have the same departure and arrival time slots. Taking into account that each time slot covers 15 minutes, I was wondering: is it possible for more than one flight to have the same departure and arrival time slots?

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! I edited your question to clarify the wording, but if I made a mistake then please edit it again, or roll back my changes. And the [tour] may be helpful if you're new to this site.

Comment: I assume the answer is yes, otherwise you wouldn't be able to schedule arrivals less than 15 minutes apart. Some airports land aircraft at the rate of 1 or more per minute. This is especially true with airports that have multiple runways that can be used concurrently.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. Besides rather small airports, most airports have quite a bit more than four arrivals/departures per hour (at very large airports, it can be more than 100+ movements/hour at peak). Could you clarify your question?

Answer (score 4):

When I was working at the FedEx hub in Memphis the pushback times were scheduled every six minutes from 1:48 to 4:00. That's 22 slots for well over 100 flights, so there were several scheduled in each slot. They were set up so only one aircraft in any particular section of ramp would be trying to push back at the same time. There would always be a queue at the runway.